# Sue enemy for peace, but the war goal province is impossible to get

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am playing as Sweden ~1537 AD and I made war against Russia with casus belli to get Nava province, located in Finland, I have claims on it.
My allies are Poland and Lithuania, theirs are Bohemia and Hungary (coalition war).
We pretty much defeated them in every battle, so the war score is greater than +10%.
I'm trying to sue Russia for peace, as head of alliance, but when I try to ask for provinces the only one available is near Lithuania. Of course I can ask for that province to become part of Lithuania, not Sweden. 
**Why isn't Neva on the list of provinces, or why is just only one province available to ask for ?**

This way it's impossible to achieve my conquest war goals, so the war was pointless, I get no benefits, despite being active and winning all battles with my armies...
Is this a bug somehow? Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 7):

You can only demand lands YOU have captured and have a core or claim on from nations the war leader is allowed to negotiate for, in many cases that will mean only the war leader but I'm going to guess Russia IS the opposing war leader in this case. If Russia is the war leader, is Neva a Russian province? If not, do they have permission to negotiate for the state Neva belongs too?

Is the province under your control? I.e have you successfully seiged it or is it under the control of an independent ally?

If it wasn't a coalition war and you were fighting a standard alliance then you'd be able to negotiate the annexation of provinces you don't have a claim on (As long as you were in control of said provinces), you'd also be able to negotiate separate peace deals with junior members. You just need to be wary of your Aggressive expansion score.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the game and I didn't know I must siege it, that has to be the problem. (Btw Russia owns the province and she is the war leader too). At first I thought I can negotiate for my war target by default.

Thanks for the answer, it surely solves my issue!

Comment: No, the province needs to be under your control before you can demand it in the peace negotiations.

Comment: Additional - I believe Russia has an decision that can move it's capital to Neva (aka St. Petersburg). If this has happened, there are special rules that apply to claiming capitals in peace deals - according to the [EUIV Wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Capital) this is not generally possible "unless it is the very last province of the country; as part of an annexation; or if it is isolated and the sole aim of the war".